# How to add a drawer menu in Android?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

this question has been asked 1000 times and after reading lot of them I'm still here with my `No drawer view found with gravity LEFT` error and blank eyes.

As far as I understood I had to create a `menu/drawer_layout.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_add"
            android:icon="@drawable/plus"
            android:title="Add" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_modify"
            android:icon="@drawable/pencil"
            android:title="Modify" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_search"
            android:icon="@drawable/search"
            android:title="Search"
            tools:ignore="DuplicateIds" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:title="Settings" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Then I had to modify a bit my `main_activity.xml` to fit the drawer :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#FF0A0A"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="auto"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.977"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Custom list:"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/listSimple" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listSimple"
                android:layout_width="403dp"
                android:layout_height="202dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText">

            </ListView>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/customListView"
                android:layout_width="408dp"
                android:layout_height="294dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.333"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.157">

            </ListView>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Simple list:"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.119"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

then I should just modify a tiny thing in my `main_activity.java` to have it right ?

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final Context context = this;
    private ArrayList<String> itemslistArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    private EditText newItemTextField;
    private ArrayAdapter simpleAdapter;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // ------------------------------- TOOLBAR -------------------------------------------------
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        // ------------------------------- DRAWER --------------------------------------------------
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, myToolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
// ------------------------------------- FLOATING BUTTON -----------------------------------------------------------
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setTitle("Add item");
                // Set up the input
                final EditText input = new EditText(context);
                // Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                builder.setView(input);

                // Set up the buttons
                builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        itemslistArray.add(input.getText().toString());
                        simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                builder.show();
            }
        });
// ------------------------------------- SIMPLE LIST -----------------------------------------------------------
        itemslistArray.add("Item1");
        itemslistArray.add("Item2");
        itemslistArray.add("Item3");
        itemslistArray.add("Item4");
        itemslistArray.add("Item5");

        simpleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemslistArray);
        final ListView simpleListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listSimple);
        simpleListView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
        // ----------------------------- LISTENNER TO MODIFY ---------------------------------------------------
        simpleListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                final int obj_position = position;
                Object o = simpleListView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setTitle("Modify item");

                // Set up the input
                final EditText input = new EditText(context);
                // Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                input.setText(o.toString());
                builder.setView(input);

                // Set up the buttons
                builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        itemslistArray.set(obj_position, input.getText().toString());
                        simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                builder.show();
            }
        });
// ------------------------------------- CUSTOM LIST -----------------------------------------------------------
        ArrayList<AndroidVersion> androidList = new ArrayList<AndroidVersion>();
        initList(androidList);
        AndroidAdapter adapter = new AndroidAdapter(this, R.layout.android_version_layout, androidList);
        final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.customListView);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
                AndroidVersion selectedItem = (AndroidVersion) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Log.v("CustomAdapterExemple", "Selected element: " + selectedItem.getVersionName());
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
...
```

[image]

I was pretty happy when I saw the hamburger on the left but as soon as I clicked I had the error so what did I make wrong ?

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: You are missing the NavigationView https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer

Comment: @JohnJoe `no drawer found with gravity left`

Comment: @PietroScarampella so I should add the fragment and the navigationview ?

Comment: @PietroScarampella it seems better only with the navigation view but how can I apply my drawer_layout.xml to this navigation view ?

Comment: Do you know we can create a new project by select a project with Navigation drawer in Android Studio?

Comment: no you don't have to add a fragment, the one provided on the docs is just an example, you can replace it with your own content

Comment: @PietroScarampella yes now it works with the example thanks !